# Optimize this query for 1000 patients in patient table

Tags: mysql

What is best to optimize this query for 1000 patients in the patient table:

```
SELECT patientid,firstname,lastname,mobilephone,email,
       Format(Coalesce((SELECT Sum(amount) - Sum(( amount * ( discount / 100 )))
FROM   invoice
WHERE  invoice.patientid = patient.patientid
       AND invoicednumber > 0) - (SELECT Sum(amount) FROM payment WHERE payment.patientid = patient.patientid), 0), 0) AS answer,
       Date_format((SELECT Max(paymentdate) FROM payment WHERE  payment.patientid = patient.patientid), '%d-%m-%Y')
       AS
       lastpaymentdate
FROM   patient
WHERE  1
```

Patient Table:
[image: Patient Table]
Invoice Table:
[image: Invoice Table]
Payment Table:
[image: Payment Table]
Result Data:
[image: Result Data]

it is taking 10 seconds on Amazon EC2 t2.micro

This is the sql fiddle example:
[image: This is the sql fiddle example]

Comment: The first step here is for you to _format_ your question so that it is readable.  Please add four or more spaces to each line of the query, so that it appears as monospaced code.

Comment: updated , thank you

Comment: I've editted it a bit, but this is not really doable. Please add some example data with a desired result, because I think you're looking for joins

Comment: What i am looking for is to get the balance "answer" , for every patient in the patient table. the blance consist of the sum of invoices and sum of discounts minus the sum of payment

Comment: Your query us unreadable. I've been puzzling at it for a few minutes, I cant decide which columns belong where. Please add a demo table with 1 patient and some numbers. I think you need to redo this whole query.

Comment: updated, Thank you for your help

Comment: updated with sql fiddle link , Thank you

Comment: is the sql fiddle just a sample or copied from your actual db schema?

Comment: It is a sample from my actual db schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor performance in any RDBM system is due to the poor design. In your SQL Fiddle, you are saving numbers in `varchar` field. Your current table engine is MyISAM which does not support relationships!? `No relationships => no index => no quick lookups`

In order to improve performance, I suggest you to change your table design.

Invoice table could have following changes. `Change Engine to InnoDB` and

```
ALTER TABLE `invoice` ENGINE = Innodb;

ALTER TABLE `invoice` 
CHANGE COLUMN `patientid` `patientid` INT(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `amount` `amount` DECIMAL(14,2) NOT NULL ,
CHANGE COLUMN `discount` `discount` DECIMAL(3,2) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
ADD INDEX `fk_invoice_patient_idx` (`patientid` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `invoice` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_invoice_patient`
  FOREIGN KEY (`patientid`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`patient` (`patientid`)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

which instantly improved any lookups between patient and invoice table. Do the same changes to your payment table and then compare your results.

After above changes you can create views for payments and invoices or subqueries like the others mentioned to speed it up more.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT patientid, firstname,lastname,mobilephone,email, FORMAT( COALESCE(
    ( SELECT SUM(amount)-SUM((amount * (discount/100))) 
    FROM invoice 
    INNER JOIN patient
    ON invoice.patientid = patient.patientid 
    and invoicednumber >0) - 
    ( SELECT SUM(amount) 
      FROM payment 
      INNER JOIN patient 
      ON payment.patientid = patient.patientid ),0),0) AS answer, 
    DATE_FORMAT(( SELECT max(paymentdate) 
                  FROM payment 
                  INNER JOIN patient 
                  ON payment.patientid = patient.patientid ),'%d-%m-%Y') As lastpaymentdate 
from patient WHERE 1
```

This will work more faster!!!!

Try it and let me know

**UPDATE**
I have replace `WHERE` clause with inner join which will help to get data in quick time.
I would also add that if indexes are not there on primary key then do add.

Comment: Please explain what you did and why you did that. SO is not a "here is the answer" kind of site, more a "this is how I got to this answer"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the answer is not calculated correctly , all the rows have the same number

Comment: Same result , Thank  you

Answer (score 0):

Although an example, your WHERE clause basically is returning ALL patients.  What is probably killing your performance is that you are doing 3 correlated queries in your field lists by querying every time for each person.  Once for invoice, and twice for payments.

Instead, I have restructured the query based on PreQuery LEFT-JOINs to the invoices and payments tables.  If you take a look, the invoice table is being pre-summarized with a GROUP BY each patient ID.  Similarly by Payments table GROUP BY each patient ID.  So at worst-case scenario, each sub-query will return at MOST one record for a given patient giving the total of all invoices and respective discounts.  For payments, a sum of all payments AND the most recent date.

So, with this starting with the patient table, I can left-join on the common patient ID you can see the simplified summary values to the final output and will be applicable for all patients.  Yes, you can still add WHERE criteria to further restrict, but this should perform significantly better.

```
SELECT 
        p.patientid, 
        p.firstname, 
        p.lastname, 
        p.mobilephone, 
        p.email,
        coalesce( PatInv.JustSumOfAmount - PatInv.DiscountedAmounts, 0 )
            - coalesce( PatPay.PaidAmounts, 0 ) Answer,
        case when PatPay.PatientID IS NULL
            then ' '
            else Date_format( PatPay.LastPaymentDate, '%d-%m-%Y') end lastpaymentdate
    FROM 
        patient p
            LEFT JOIN
            ( select 
                    i.patientID,
                    sum( i.amount ) justSumOfAmount,
                    sum( i.amount * ( discount / 100 )) as discountedAmounts
                from
                    invoice i
                where
                    i.invoicedNumber > 0
                group by
                    i.patientID
                order by
                    i.patientid ) PatInv
                on p.patientid = patInv.patientID
            LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT
                    pay.patientID, 
                    Sum(pay.amount) paidAmounts,
                    max( pay.paymentDate ) LastPaymentDate
                FROM
                    payment pay
                group by
                    pay.patientID 
                order by
                    pay.patientid ) PatPay
                on p.patientID = patPay.PatientID
```

I have posted this query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40945d/7)  Additionally, looking at your tables, your invoice and payment tables SHOULD EACH have an index on the Patient ID to help optimize the querying.  I dont know if this was a sample post oversight from your sql-fiddle vs production, but that too would have an impact on performance.

The SQLFiddle option I have takes 5ms vs your 2-3ms, but that is only for the few records provided.  I would bet that against your 1000+ patients and 1000's of transactions in each invoice and payment table this will make this query option faster than the correlated queries.

Think of your query as this.  I have 1000 patients.  Query the invoice table 1000 times, query the payment table 2000 times (1000 for the sum of payments, another 1000 times for the most recent date per patient).

My query -- Prequery the invoice table once and summarize 1 record per patient.  Prequery the payment table once and summarize 1 record per patient. Join patients to these two subtables directly by ID.